# Is the entire second half of the original Naruto series just fillers?

Tags: naruto

I've been told that the entire second half of Naruto is fillers, if this is true then I wasted 3 months of my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The fight between Naruto and Saskue where the two ninja statues are is the "end" of cannon Naruto.

The manga then did a story about how Kakashi got his sharingan then went straight into what is "Naruto Shuppiden"